# Trying to create VB.Net Integration for EdgeJS

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, node.js, edge.js

I have created [this project](https://github.com/Jabark/edge-vb), which is basically an attempted clone of [this project](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge-cs) but converted from C# to VB using [SharpDevelop 4.4](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Download/) and then built using VS 2015

My issue can be found on GitHub [here](https://github.com/Jabark/edge-vb/issues/1), but here's the error I'm getting when I run my NodeJS project:

[image: EdgeVB Error]

My bit of code in my NodeJS project that isn't working:

```
var WriteCrapVB = edge.func('vb', function () {
/*
    Function(input)
        Console.WriteLine("Hello from .NET")
        Return Nothing
    End Function
*/
});
var hello = WriteCrapVB(null);
hello(null); // prints out "Hello from .NET"
```

When running this C# it does work:

```
var WriteCrapCS = edge.func('cs', function () {
/*
    async (input) =>
    {
        return (Func<object,Task<object>>)(async (i) => { 
            Console.WriteLine("Hello from .NET"); 
            return null; 
        });
    }
*/
});
var hello = WriteCrapCS(null, true);
hello(null, true); // prints out "Hello from .NET"
```

I have basically tried to use [this guide](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge/wiki/Add-support-for-a-CLR-language) to create this project.

I've tried various things to fix this bug, each as unhelpful as the previous one. I'm hoping someone with greater .NET knowledge than I can point out a glaringly obvious mistake!

Please help this poor soul from going bald from hair tearing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## ***facepalm***

Root namespace must be blank.

[image: Make Blank Namespace]